# How to Implement Audit trial in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

We have developed an asp.net mvc application and is live for 2 years.
Now our client is asking for Audit Trail.

### Requirement

- Should be able to define which column / table needs to be audited
- Should be able to create a report based on the same.

**Below is our current scenario**

- We are using SQL Server 2012 as backend
- Our data access layer communicated to DB only through Store Procedure.
- We are not using any model binders.

What is the best way to implement audit trail in the current scenario?

Comment: SO is unlikely to help you with figuring out what legal requirements you client imply when asking for "Audit Trail". Also even if you'd specify exact list of requirements the question will likely be too broad/opinion based for SO.

Comment: Please read [ask] for information about what makes a good question. As @AlexeiLevenkov mentions, this question is too broad. Specifically because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service -- some of us get paid to create such "audit trails"...

Comment: Audit trail is a business concept. The type of data you need to audit are business requirements. The tools can only "audit" actions related to *them*, eg log ASP.NET requests or SQL Server queries but these have no meaning to business users. You need to decide what business actions need to be audited, then write records somewhere (eg in a database) when they start, at each individual step in them, when they finish and enough data to satisfy the auditor's requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Define the business scenarios that need to be audited.
- Identify the code entry points where those scenarios happen
- Design the audit data model based on what data you want/need to store
- Write data in your audit table/tables on the previously identified code entry points

This answer is intentionally vague. Auditing is not something that ASP.NET or any framework can do for you. This is usually intimately related to your business logic code and requirements